# Emberjs Query params don't work on re-visit

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a users route that has params like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/#/users/index?page=2&pageSize=1
```

The problem is if I go to page 2 then go to a whole different route then go back to
`http://localhost:8000/#/users/index` It still shows me page 2 instead of the default of page 1. I have spent a day tracking this down and can't figure it out - please help.

This is the flow:

- go to users page a request is made to `http://localhost:8000/api/users?page=1&pageSize=1&query=&status=active` (CORRECT)
- click on page 2 a request is made to `http://localhost:8000/api/users?page=2&pageSize=1&query=&status=active` (CORRECT)
- click on a different route (no request made - CORRECT)
- click on the users link which has NO query params, a request is made to `http://localhost:8000/api/users?page=2&pageSize=1&query=&status=active` (WRONG - url has no query params should default to page 1)
- again click on a different route
- again click on the users link and a requesti is made to `http://localhost:8000/api/users?page=1&pageSize=1&query=&status=active` (CORRECT, page is set correctly to 1 as it should have been)

Here is some code to give you an idea.

```
App.UsersIndexRoute = App.AuthenticatedRoute.extend(App.PaginationRouteMixin,{
  queryParams: {
    query: {refreshModel: true},
    status: {refreshModel:true}
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('user',params);
  },
});

App.UsersIndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend(App.PaginationMixin,{
  needs:['users'],
  queryParams: ['query','status'],
  query: '',
  status:'active'
});

App.PaginationRouteMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  queryParams: {
    page: {refreshModel:true},
    pageSize: {refreshModel:true},
  }
});

App.PaginationMixin = Em.Mixin.create({
  pagination: function () {
    if (this.get('model.isLoaded')) {
      modelType = this.get('model.type');
      return this.get('store').typeMapFor(modelType).metadata.pagination;
    }
  }.property('model.isLoaded'),

  pages: function() {
    var availablePages = this.get('availablePages'),
    pages = [],
    page;
    for (i = 0; i < availablePages; i++) {
      page = i + 1;
      pages.push({ page_id: page.toString() });
    }
    return pages;
  }.property('availablePages'),

  currentPage: function() {
    return parseInt(this.get('pagination.CurrentPage'), 10) || 1;
  }.property('pagination'),

  nextPage: function() {
    var nextPage = this.get('currentPage') + 1;
    var availablePages = this.get('availablePages');
    if (nextPage <= availablePages) {
      return Ember.Object.create({id: nextPage});
    }else{
      return Ember.Object.create({id: this.get('currentPage')});
    }
  }.property('currentPage', 'availablePages'),

  prevPage: function() {
    var prevPage = this.get('currentPage') - 1;
    if (prevPage > 0) {
      return Ember.Object.create({id: prevPage});
    }else{
      return Ember.Object.create({id: this.get('currentPage')});
    }
  }.property('currentPage'),

  availablePages: function() {
    return this.get('pagination.PageCount');
  }.property('pagination'),

  pageSize:"10",
  page:"1",
  queryParams:['page','pageSize'],
  actions:{
    setPage:function(pageId){
      this.set('page', pageId);
    }
  }

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are the query params stored in a service of some sort? If so, I'd wager you need to clean that.

Comment: Doesn't your extension of the mixin for the route mean that you're overriding the mixin's value of the queryParams object? Is that intended?

Comment: Would be interested to see your link-to "calls" as well. Are you 100% SURE that they don't have any query-params encoded on the links?

Comment: Also it seems you haven't added page and pageSize to your queryparams in your controller. Is it intentional that you left it out? Why not start smaller, and simpler, and slowly introduced functionality testing each bit one piece at a time? Then you'd know where it went wrong.

Comment: @mingos query params not stored anywhere else.

Comment: @JulianLeviston it doesn't override, ember merges them and i am 100% sure the link has no params. i even hardcoded a link and it did the same thing. you can remove everything in the mixin and just keep the query params and it will do the same thing.

Comment: @eibrahim in that case I reckon you ought to create a jsbin, then re-open your issue in ember.js and ping machty and attach the jsbin (I know you've already attached this particualr issue). Apologies for making you do a dance back and forth, but your initial issue on emberjs was a bit light on details and a jsbin is **always** better.